# Could not find "AddResource" method when pulling docker images

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-pull

I am pulling a docker image from docker hub. But it accounts a error. It says that "AddResource"  method could not be found:

```
docker: error adding content digest to lease: sha256:31168c113862cce4cef6b16b20cdef1b126eb755492a6030ca68a9020b7eb657: unknown method AddResource: not implemented.
```

I have tried some times, and tried to pull different images. The error is the same.
The docker version is:

```
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:34:59 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:40 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.4
  GitCommit:        e6b3f5632f50dbc4e9cb6288d911bf4f5e95b18e
 runc:
  Version:          1.2.4
  GitCommit:        6635b4f0c6af3810594d2770f662f34ddc15b40d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it turned out that due to a bug in containerd, I hadn't updated it for a while. So updating the containerd using

```
sudo pacman -Sy containerd
```

and restarting both services

```
sudo systemctl restart containerd.service
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

fixed the issue. Now I have:

```
docker version               
Client:
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.15.6
 Git commit:        831ebeae96
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 22:25:01 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.15.6
  Git commit:       f0014860c1
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 22:24:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b.m
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

and the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when there is a mismatch between the `docker-client` version and the `docker-server` version. In your case, they seem to be the same, but, I would recommend re-installing them, if you're on ubuntu perform:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-ce
sudo apt-get remove docker-ce-cli


sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli=5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs) --assume-yes 
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs) --assume-yes
```

Note: I have a newer containerD:

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:34:59 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:40 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: The problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when pulling an image on an arm machine and pull the image successfully after reinstalling the docker using the solution upstairs.

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo dpkg -r docker.io
sudo dpkg -i (containerd, docker-ce-cli, docker-ce that have the same version)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users: (same as @hhadi answer)

```
sudo apt install containerd
```

This solved the issue for me :)